# prevent screen to turn on when incoming call android

Tags: android

When Android phone receives an incoming call from a specific number the phone's ringing the screen should not blink. What I mean is the user should not be able to know that there was incoming call, but actually there was because i am blocking the incoming call through telephony manager but before ending call through telephony manager in broadcast receiver screen lights up that cause use in suspicion that something has happened.

Any help in this regard will be really appreciable.